# Helmert transformation in pyproj

Tags: proj, pyproj

I have a set of coordinate points projected in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) and a raster specific coordinate system and have calculated the translation, rotation and scale for a Helmert transformation (P' = T + sRP).

I can confirm that the destination points P' are correct, The following gives correct coordinate pairs:

```
x = x0 + s * np.cos(theta) * x_src + s * np.sin(theta) * y_src
y = y0 - s * np.sin(theta) * x_src + s * np.cos(theta) * y_src
```

I am then trying to set up a transformation in `pyproj` to do the same thing, e.g.

```py
pipeline = f"""
+proj=helmert
    +x={x0:.3f} +y={y0:.3f}
    +s={s:.3f} +theta={np.rad2deg(theta) * 3600:.3f}
"""
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_pipeline(pipeline)
x, y = transformer.transform(x_src, y_src)
```

But this gives me very different results.

```
source:  (16140013.539, -4552024.619)
dest:    (1846.073, -1204.140)
by hand: (1845.954, -1204.294)
proj4:   (4853.370, -1640.174)
```

I assume this is either something to do with my parameter normalisation, or how the input to my transformation is interpreted, but I've exceeded my understanding of Proj4.

Comment: I recommend asking your question here: https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/proj

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go and report back anything useful.